# Specifying an angle and a length using the `let-in` syntax

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have `$\triangle{ABC}$` and a line `$\ell$` through the midpoints of two sides of the triangle drawn.  `$\ell$` is parallel to `$\overline{BC}$`.  In the last few lines of the code, I am trying to draw another line `k` through `A`  parallel to  `$\ell$` and `$\overline{BC}$`.  I want `k` to extend above `$\overline{AC}$` by the same amount that `$\ell$` does. I tried using the following command.

```
\draw[dashed, green] let \p1=($(upper_left_arrowhead)-(A)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in (A) -- ($(A) +(\n1:{veclen(\x1,\y1)})$);
```

It seems to me that I cannot use both `\n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}` and `veclen(\x1,\y1)` in the `\draw` command.

The code compiles because I put `%` in front of the last three lines.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}


%The vertices of a triangle are located.
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (20:7);
\coordinate (C) at ($(B) +(150:3)$);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

%The midpoint of AB is called P.
\coordinate (P) at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$);
\path[name path=the_part_of_ell_through_AB] let \p1=($(B)-(C)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in (P) -- ($(P) +(\n1:2.5)$);
\path[name path=the_part_of_ell_through_AC] let \p1=($(B)-(C)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in (P) -- ($(P) +({\n1+180}:4)$);

%The arrowheads of line $\ell$ are to be drawn at the intersections of the horizontal and
%vertical lines through A.
\path[name path=the_vertical_line_through_A] (A) -- ($(A) +(0,3.5)$);
\path[name path=the_horizontal_line_through_A] (A) -- ($(A) +(6,0)$);

\coordinate[name intersections={of=the_part_of_ell_through_AC and the_vertical_line_through_A, by=upper_left_arrowhead}];
\coordinate[name intersections={of=the_part_of_ell_through_AB and the_horizontal_line_through_A, by=lower_right_arrowhead}];
\draw[latex-latex] (upper_left_arrowhead) -- (lower_right_arrowhead);
\draw let \p1=($(B)-(C)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor={\n1+180}, inner sep=0] at ($(lower_right_arrowhead) + (\n1:0.15)$){$\ell$};

%Sides $\overline{AP}$ and $\overline{BP}$ are marked with "|".
\draw ($($(A)!0.5!(P)$)!3pt!90:(P)$) -- ($($(A)!0.5!(P)$)!3pt!-90:(P)$);
\draw ($($(B)!0.5!(P)$)!3pt!90:(P)$) -- ($($(B)!0.5!(P)$)!3pt!-90:(P)$);


%The labels for the vertices of the triangle are typeset.
\draw let \p1=($(A)-(B)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(A)-(C)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in node[anchor={0.5*(\n1+\n2)}, inner sep=0] at ($(A) + ({0.5*(\n1+\n2)+180}:0.15)$){$A$};

\draw let \p1=($(B)-(A)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(B)-(C)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in node[anchor={0.5*(\n1+\n2)+180}, inner sep=0] at ($(B) + ({0.5*(\n1+\n2)}:0.15)$){$B$};

\draw let \p1=($(C)-(B)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(C)-(A)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in node[anchor={0.5*(\n1-180+\n2)}, inner sep=0] at ($(C) + ({0.5*(\n1-180+\n2)+180}:0.15)$){$C$};

%The label for the midpoint of AB is typeset.
\draw let \p1=($(B)-(A)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(B)-(C)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in node[anchor={0.5*(\n1-180+\n2)+180}, inner sep=0] at ($(P) + ({0.5*(\n1-180+\n2)}:0.15)$){$P$};


%A line k is drawn through A that is parallel to BC. k is to extend above side AC as much as $\ell$ does,
%and k is to extend below side AB as much as $\ell$ does.
%\draw[dashed, green] let \p1=($(upper_left_arrowhead)-(A)$) in (A) -- ($(A) +({atan(\y1/\x1)}:{veclen(\x1,\y1)})$);
%\draw[dashed, green] let \p1=($(upper_left_arrowhead)-(A)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in (A) -- ($(A) +(\n1:{veclen(\x1,\y1)})$);
%\draw[dashed] let \p1=($(lower_right_arrowhead)-(A)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in (A) -- ($(A) +({atan(\y1/\x1)}:{veclen(\x1,\y1)})$);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that `(upper_left_arrowhead)` is directly above `(A)`. Hence, `\x1` is equal to zero and, hence, `\y1/\x1` cannot be calculated. TeX tells you this on the console. It has nothing to do with `veclen`. The compilation isn't getting that far.

I'm a bit unclear why you are doing things in ways which appear needlessly complex. For example, why such a performance to label the vertices and midpoint?

Why not just, for example

```
  \coordinate [label=below left:$A$] (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate [label=right:$B$] (B) at (20:7);
  \coordinate [label=above:$C$] (C) at ($(B) +(150:3)$);

  ...

  \coordinate [label=below:$P$] (P) at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$);
  \path[name path=the_part_of_ell_through_AB] let \p1=($(B)-(C)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in (P) -- ($(P) +(\n1:2.5)$) node {$\ell$};
```

which does essentially the same thing, as far as I can tell?

I think for the new path, you want something like the following.

Change the drawing of line *l* so that the path is named `upper path`:

```
  \draw[latex-latex,name path=upper path] (upper_left_arrowhead) -- (lower_right_arrowhead);
```

Now name a path from *A* to *C*:

```
  \path [name path=ac] (A) -- (C);
```

and get the intersection of these lines:

```
  \coordinate [name intersections={of=upper path and ac, by=intersect}];
```

Then draw the relevant parts of *l* shifted so that they are relative to *A* rather than to the intersections of *l* with *AB* and *AC*:

```
  \draw [dashed, green] ($(upper_left_arrowhead)-(intersect)$) -- ($(lower_right_arrowhead)-(P)$);
```

[image: l and k]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  %The vertices of a triangle are located.
  \coordinate [label=below left:$A$] (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate [label=right:$B$] (B) at (20:7);
  \coordinate [label=above:$C$] (C) at ($(B) +(150:3)$);
  \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

  %The midpoint of AB is called P.
  \coordinate [label=below:$P$] (P) at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$);
  \path[name path=the_part_of_ell_through_AB] let \p1=($(B)-(C)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in (P) -- ($(P) +(\n1:2.5)$) node {$\ell$};
  \path[name path=the_part_of_ell_through_AC] let \p1=($(B)-(C)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in (P) -- ($(P) +({\n1+180}:4)$);

  %The arrowheads of line $\ell$ are to be drawn at the intersections of the horizontal and
  %vertical lines through A.
  \path[name path=the_vertical_line_through_A] (A) -- ($(A) +(0,3.5)$);
  \path[name path=the_horizontal_line_through_A] (A) -- ($(A) +(6,0)$);

  \coordinate[name intersections={of=the_part_of_ell_through_AC and the_vertical_line_through_A, by=upper_left_arrowhead}];
  \coordinate[name intersections={of=the_part_of_ell_through_AB and the_horizontal_line_through_A, by=lower_right_arrowhead}];
  \draw[latex-latex,name path=upper path] (upper_left_arrowhead) -- (lower_right_arrowhead);

  %Sides $\overline{AP}$ and $\overline{BP}$ are marked with "|".
  \draw ($($(A)!0.5!(P)$)!3pt!90:(P)$) -- ($($(A)!0.5!(P)$)!3pt!-90:(P)$);
  \draw ($($(B)!0.5!(P)$)!3pt!90:(P)$) -- ($($(B)!0.5!(P)$)!3pt!-90:(P)$);

  \path [name path=ac] (A) -- (C);
  \coordinate [name intersections={of=upper path and ac, by=intersect}];
  \draw [dashed, green] ($(upper_left_arrowhead)-(intersect)$) -- ($(lower_right_arrowhead)-(P)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your comments have been helpful.  Thanks.  I have edited the code to get the exact diagram that I had intended.